# ORA-00604, ORA-30512 when modifying AUDIT DDL Index

Tags: database, oracle11g, sqlplus

I'm getting the ORA-00604 and ORA-30512 error when I'm trying to alter my AUDIT DDL index, the code that I'm executing on sql-plus is:

```
ALTER INDEX "MY_SCHEMA"."AU_DDL_INDEX"
    NOPARALLEL;

COMMIT;
```

Does anybody know something about that?

Thanks a lot.

Regards.

Comment: ORA-00604 is "error occurred at recursive SQL level x". ORA-30512 is "Cannot modify <table> more than once in a transaction". There may have a SCHEMA trigger in place which is performing some sort of DDL. Best of luck.

Comment: +1 to @BobJarvis. `select count(*) from all_triggers where table_name = 'AU_DDL_INDEX'` will tell you how many triggers are on there.

Comment: @mmmmmpie - good suggestion. In addition, if a SCHEMA-level trigger is involved it can be found with `SELECT * FROM DBA_TRIGGERS WHERE BASE_OBJECT_TYPE = 'SCHEMA'`.

Comment: And you don't need COMMIT after DDL

Answer (score 0):

Your index is probably on a table that is referenced on an Audit DDL Trigger. You have to disable the audit DDL trigger in order to alter the table that the trigger references.

From documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/errmg/ORA-29250.html

> ORA-30512: cannot modify string.string more than once in a transaction
> Cause: An attempt was made to modify an object more than once in a transaction. This error is usually caused by a DDL statement that fires a system trigger that tries to modify the same object. It can also happen when an attempt is made to perform more than one DDL operation on a queue table in the same transaction without issuing a commit between operations.

> Action: Do not create system triggers that might modify an already modified object. Also, do not specify more than one DDL operation on a queue table in the same transaction.